# ¿De dónde viene la palabra "marihuana"?

Tags: etimología, plantas

[**Marihuana**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OPtFZ2y) aparece definido en el DLE como

> Tb. mariguana.
>
> 1. f. cáñamo índico.
>
> 2. f. Producto elaborado a partir del cáñamo índico, que, al ser fumado, produce efectos eufóricos o narcóticos.

y [**mariguana**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OPpPqqj) simplemente remite a [**marihuana**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OPtFZ2y) sin ninguna indicación, en ninguno de los casos, de su posible etimología.

De acuerdo con el NTLLE, aparece por primera vez en el DLE de 1956:

> **Mariaguana [~huana]**. f. En Méjico y otros países americanos, nombre del cañamo común, cuyas hojas, fumadas como el tabaco, producn un terrible efecto narcótico.

En el CORDE apenas aparece una docena de veces, siendo el texto más antiguo de  Fedérico Gamboa (*Suprema Ley*, 1896, México):

> Como único consuelo, la *marihuana* que fumaban a escondidas.

La propia definición del DLE de 1956 y el hecho de que el primer texto en que se recoge sea de México me hace **suponer** un posible orígen mejicano de la palabra, pero no encuentro nada que lo corrobore o contradiga.

¿De dónde viene la palabra **marihuana**?

Comment: Pues yo siempre he creído que venía de "María Juana"...

Answer (score 3):

En el artículo de Wikipedia en inglés sobre la palabra *[marijuana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marijuana_(word))* se discuten varias etimologías posibles, que paso a resumir.

En varias fuentes se cita la primera aparición de la palabra en 1894 como *mariguan*, de la cual *marihuana* sería una alteración. Hubo muchas otras variantes registradas. En cada caso hay que tener en cuenta que puede tratarse de una misma palabra transcripta de diferentes maneras por oyentes extranjeros o poco familiarizados con la cultura local y usando diferentes convenciones ortográficas. En cualquier caso parece claro que la palabra *marihuana* (con *h*) es de origen mexicano

Se ha hablado de una conexión con un término náhuatl, *mallihuan* "prisionero", pero los expertos la descartan. *Cannabis sativa* no existía en América antes de la llegada de los conquistadores españoles, y el término náhuatl no tiene ninguna conexión semántica clara con la planta.

Una posible origen es la expresión del chino *ma ren hua* "flor de la semilla del cáñamo". Otra es la raíz semítica  **m-r-j* que significa "cáñamo". En el artículo se dice que la palabra semítica fue tomada en préstamo por el chino; esto parece muy extraño. En chino cada sílaba es un morfema y difícilmente podría tomarse prestada una palabra semítica trisilábica; lo que sí podría ocurrir, supongo, es que un hablante de chino reinterpretase una palabra semítica trisilábica que significase "cáñamo" como tres palabras chinas que significasen algo similar (una forma de [reanálisis morfémico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rean%C3%A1lisis_morf%C3%A9mico)). Esta misma raíz semítica es la fuente probable de la palabra castellana *[mejorana](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origanum_majorana)* (una especie de orégano originado en el Mediterráneo oriental).

*Marijuana*, con *j*, es una de las tantas formas de la palabra *marihuana* (con *h* muda, obviamente) que quizá fue influida por la similitud con el nombre *María Juana*. Esta influencia ocurre en el paso del español mexicano al inglés de Estados Unidos, y no antes; hay abundante registro de *marihuana* con *h* en México a principios del siglo XX, y sólo después de que la droga se popularizara en Estados Unidos se produce la aparición de la forma con *j*.

Comment: Además hay una propuesta que dice que la mari(j|g|h)uana proviene de antiguas voces precolombinas e incluso una teoría que dice ser una derivación directa del árabe, del *marwana* == dura , valiente. (según Fernando A. Navarro)

Answer (score 1):

Parece que, definitivamente, la palabra es originaria de México. No puedo dejar de hacer referencia a una etimología popular a la que los etimólogos más respetados no dan credibilidad, pero no deja de ser curiosa. Aparece mencionada en la web de [etimologías deChile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?marihuana).

En México se usa la voz ***[juan](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MYZXqRp)*** para referirse a los soldados rasos. Y si "juan" eran los soldados, "juanas" o "marijuanas" eran las prostitutas cuarteleras y [soldaderas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YGMFIk5) que les acompañaban. Dado que las drogas eran difundidas en entornos castrenses y cuarteleros y hacían igual compañía a los soldados, no es descabellado pensar que estos denominaran "marijuana" a dicha droga.

Hay puntos a favor de esta teoría, pero habría que comprobar desde cuándo se denomina "juan" a un soldado en México. La palabra *marihuana* parece tener ya más de siglo y medio, como demuestra el texto más antiguo que he encontrado en la hemeroteca de la BNE que la usa:

> *En las tropas que formaron el cantón de Jalapa, se observó una enfermedad bien singular, y que justamente reclamó la atención de las primeras autoridades: los individuos atacados quedaban sin fuerzas, lánguidos, aturdidos, y terminaba la escena por un profundo sopor. El uso de una yerba conocida con el nombre de marihuana, que los soldados fumaban como el tabaco, era la causa de esta rara enfermedad.*
>
> Diario oficial del Gobierno Mexicano. 2/4/1846, página 2.

Habrá que ver si el uso de *juan* es anterior a este texto, pero de momento no he encontrado ningún texto que lo corrobore. Al menos sí que describe el efecto que producía la droga al ser usada por tropas, lo que confirma su uso en entornos militares.

Como apunte, la RAE recoge la voz *mariguana* desde 1927, pero en la versión "Academia manual". En 1956 se incorporó al "Academia usual" la voz *marihuana*.